# Python warnings filter not catching InsecurePlatformWarning

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, urllib3

Since this message

> lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>     InsecurePlatformWarning

has been flooding my logs (yes, I know it is important, I will fix the real problem eventually! I promise!), I want to add a filter to have it only show up once.
So I added this:

```
warnings.simplefilter(action='once', category=InsecurePlatformWarning, append=True)
```

but it doesn't filter anything.
When I do this:

```
warnings.simplefilter(action='once', append=True)
```

It does that for all the warnings, which is not what I want, but it shows the code is indeed being executed and the filter itself does work.

What am I doing wrong in terms of Category?
I don't want to disable warnings. I just want to make this specific warning only show up once for now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `append=True`:

```
warnings.simplefilter(action='once', category=InsecurePlatformWarning)
```

The urllib3 code [already has default logging configuration](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/__init__.py#L58). If you use `append=True`, then the default configuration overrides yours.